# Error when using the .split() function with urllib.request

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror, urllib, python-3.6

I am trying to split bbc's source into two parts in order to get the top headline:

```
import urllib.request

url = 'http://www.bbc.com/'
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
contents = page.read()
page.close()

split1 = '<a class="media__link" href="/news/world-us-canada-39965107" rev="hero1|headline">\n'
split2 = '\n</a>'

title = contents.split(split1)[1].split(split2)[1]

print(title)
```

But I am getting this error:

```
title = contents.split(split1)[1].split(split2)[1]
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: `contents` is of type `bytes`, so it can only be `split` by delimiters of that type.

Comment: You need to pass a `bytes` type object in Python3. It looks like you're trying to just split up the URL reference (href), so why not take a look at [urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `HTTPResponse.read([amt])`:
>
> Reads and returns the response body, or up to the next amt bytes.

```
contents = page.read()
```

returns a bytes object, not str.  So the splitting delimiter needs to also be bytes object. Just add a `b` in front of the string.

```
split1 = b'<a class="media__link" href="/news/world-us-canada-39965107" rev="hero1|headline">\n'
split2 = b'\n</a>'
```